# Symfony 2.8 - Set default value with data from session and propel

Tags: forms, symfony, default-value, propel

I use Propel in a project & I try to set default value my form which uses a ModelType input and I need to set a default value stored in session in this form and where this session is not null for the stored value used in this functionnality.

This is my form :

```
   /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Fcl\VitrinellisBundle\Model\ProfileVariety',
            'name' => 'profile_variety_search',
            'locales' => ['fr'],
            'session' => null
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', ModelType::class, array(
                'class'       => 'Fcl\VitrinellisBundle\Model\ProfileVariety',
                'query'       => ProfileVarietyQuery::create()->orderById(),
                'property'    => 'name',
                'label'       => 'Profil recherché',
                'expanded'    => false,
                'multiple'    => false,
                'required'    => false,
                'placeholder' => '- Filtrer par profil -',
                'attr' => array(
                    'onchange' => 'submit()',
                    'class'    => 'col s3'
                )
            ))
        ;
    }
```

This is my treatment :

```
    public function listAction(Request $request = null)
    {
        $pModelManager = $this->get('fcl_vitrinellis.p_model_manager');
        $profileVarietyManager = $this->get('fcl_vitrinellis.profile_variety_manager');
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $profileVariety = new ProfileVariety();
        $models = null;

        $form = $this->createForm(ProfileVarietySearchType::class, $profileVariety);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if (null != $form['name']->getData()) {
                $models =  $pModelManager->getWebsiteByModel($form['name']->getData()->getName());
                $session->set('profileVarietySearch', $form['name']->getData()->getName());
            } else {
                $models = $pModelManager->getList();
            }
        } else {
            if ($session->has('profileVarietySearch') && null != $session->get('profileVarietySearch')) {
                $models = $pModelManager->getWebsiteByModel($session->get('profileVarietySearch'));
            } else {
                $models = $pModelManager->getList();
            }
        }

        return $this->render('console\p_model_list.html.twig', array(
            'objArray' => $models,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

I have try to set default data with 'data' option and with PRE_SET_DATA event in the form but I had satisfactory result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an other solution.

Create new Model which his name is ProfileVarietySearch, like this :

```
class ProfileVarietySearch
{
    /** @var null|ProfileVariety $profileVariety */
    private $profileVariety;

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function is_empty()
    {
        return is_null($this->profileVariety);
    }

    /**
     * @return null|ProfileVariety
     */
    public function getProfileVariety()
    {
        return $this->profileVariety;
    }

    /**
     * @param $profileVariety
     *
     * @return ProfileVarietySearch
     */
    public function setProfileVariety($profileVariety): self
    {
        $this->profileVariety = $profileVariety;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

In the controller, write this :

```
    public function listAction(Request $request = null)
    {
        $pModelManager = $this->get('fcl_vitrinellis.p_model_manager');
        $profileVarietyManager = $this->get('fcl_vitrinellis.profile_variety_manager');
        $session = $request->getSession();
        $profileVarietySearch = new ProfileVarietySearch();
        $models = null;

        if ($session->has('profileVarietySearch') && null != $session->get('profileVarietySearch')) {
           $profileVarietySearch->setProfileVariety(
               $profileVarietyManager->getByName($session->get('profileVarietySearch'))->getData()[0]
           );
        }



        $form = $this->createForm(ProfileVarietySearchType::class, $profileVarietySearch);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if (null != $form->getData()->getProfileVariety()) {
                $models =  $pModelManager->getWebsiteByModel($form->getData()->getProfileVariety()->getName());
                $session->set('profileVarietySearch', $form->getData()->getProfileVariety()->getName());
            } else {
                $session->set('profileVarietySearch', null);
                $models = $pModelManager->getList();
            }
        } else {
            if ($session->has('profileVarietySearch') && null != $session->get('profileVarietySearch')) {
                $models = $pModelManager->getWebsiteByModel($session->get('profileVarietySearch'));
            } else {
                $models = $pModelManager->getList();
            }
        }

        return $this->render($this->view_list, array(
            'objArray' => $models,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

In the ProfileVarietySearchType, write this :

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Fcl\VitrinellisBundle\Form\Model\ProfileVarietySearch',
        'name' => 'profile_variety_search'
    ));
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('profileVariety', ModelType::class, array(
        'class'       => 'Fcl\VitrinellisBundle\Model\ProfileVariety',
        'query'       => ProfileVarietyQuery::create()->orderById(),
        'property'    => 'name',
        'label'       => 'Profil recherché',
        'expanded'    => false,
        'multiple'    => false,
        'required'    => false,
        'placeholder' => '- Filtrer par profil -',
        'attr' => array(
            'onchange' => 'submit()',
            'class'    => 'col s3'
        )
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In an EntityType the incoming default 'data' must be an object of the right type. I would first try to see if we have incoming form data.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    // Check form data
    $formDataEntity = $builder->getData();

    // Check if it has the field filled in
    if ($formDataEntity && $formDataEntity->getName()) {
         $objToSet = $formDataEntity->getName();
    } else {
         $objToSet = $options['incomingDefaultObject'];
    )

    $builder
        ->add('name', ModelType::class, array(
            class => 'Fcl\VitrinellisBundle\Model\ProfileVariety',
            data => $objToSet,
            ...
```

And then for the resolver

```
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'incomingDefaultObject' => null,
    ));
}
```

And you call the form with the default opion in the controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(YourType::class, $yourObject, array('incomingDefaultObject' => $nameObject));
```

Warning: if a user decides to leave the field empty this code will always set the default.

Comment: Thx for your help @Julesezaar, your solution work perfectly ! :O